# Email receiving in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses, mx-record

I tried configuring AWS SES for receiving emails into my AWS S3 bucket, but I couldn't find any

Step performed -

1. Domain verified
2. Added TXT value (BigRock.in)
3. Added MX value in Domain's DNS (BigRock.in)
4. Email address verified
5. Created an active rule set
6. In S3 action bucket named(xyz-emails), AMAZON_SES_SETUP_NOTIFICATION has received.

But when I tried emailing self (using verified email address), email does not reach my S3 bucket.

Please help in case I'm missing out any step during configuration.

Regards,
Sushant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your ARNs, it may be an error somewhere, or at a policy level
Just take a careful read at the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html

Comment: For test environment we have kept bucket policy public, so there shouldn't be any issue over ARN or policy issue

Comment: Also when I try sending test mails from AWS console, they were successful

Comment: Do you have access to the logs at each part of the process? I mean the sending email server, aws, etc